# Is it possible to only scan specific WiFi channels using Android?

Tags: android

As an experiment, I want to try using WiFi SSIDs to set small amounts of data. Apparently it takes Android 1.2 seconds to do a complete WiFi scan (0.1s for each of the 12 channels). If I only use 1 WiFi channel, is there a way to prevent Android from scanning the other 11 channels?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46639/scan-a-single-channel-to-measure-rssi-of-a-specific-ap-when-not-associated